# Getting started with ftp4j

Tags: ftp4j

I can't seem to even be able to get started using ftp4j.

I have:
    FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
    ftp.connect(address);
    ftp.login(user, pass);

It just keeps saying package ftp does not exist.

Can someone tell me what i'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
ftp.connect(strHostname,intPort);      //Default port for FTP is 21
ftp.setPassive(true);
ftp.login(strUsername,strPassword);
ftp.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);
ftp.disconnect(true);
```

[For more examples check this out](http://techdive.in/java/ftp4j-file-transfer-protocol-tutorial)

> and dont miss out to add ftp4j package in your CLASSPATH

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but if it says ftp4j package does not exist you need to make sure that you typed:

> import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient;

and you have the package ftp4j-1.7.2.jar in the folder "libs".